# Jasper report - exclude table component columnFooter and tableFooter on export

Tags: jasper-reports

I have report template and requirement to exclude part of table when exporting report to excel.

Report have summary band with table component inside. I set up properties as below. It works for columnHeader, but cannot make it work work for columnFooter and tableFooter.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.1" value="*"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.4" value="columnFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.report.4" value="*"/>
```

Anyobody know the trick?

Comment: I have test and meet same problem, the only way that I managed to remove columnFooter and tableFooter was excluding the reportElements on key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/994071/exclude-table-component-columnfooter-and-tablefooter-export) response from jasper staff and it solved my problem.

> Table column footer cells actually end up rendering as a page footer
>   band in a subreport generated for the table. Therefore if you want to
>   exclude the column footer cells you'll need to define a property for
>   pageFooter.      A defect or feature request for improvement in
>   the product for this issue has already been filed against JR Library
>   6.2.x

Comment: Strange, I am already suppressing the page footer, but it is not preventing the table footer from exporting to csv.

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper Server 6.1 suppressing page footers in table subreport (as a workaround) like this **didn't** work:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.4" value="*"/>
```

I managed to solve this as Petter Friberg suggested by setting keys for all elements inside jr:tableFooter:

```
<reportElement key="tableFooter" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="fd"/>
```

and setting exclusion properties:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.key.6" value="tableFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.6" value="*"/>
```